# how to set background of the specific row of listview in android?

Tags: android, android-listview

In my application, the user orders a household product, and the application displays PRODUCT NAME & PRICE in list view, I want to set different background for **out of stock** products. Can anyone help me.

public class Products extends BaseAdapter {

```
public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list;
Activity activity;

boolean Connection;

public Products(Activity activity,
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list) {
    super();
    this.activity = activity;
    this.list = list;
}

public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return list.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return list.get(position);
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

class ViewHolder {

    TextView item_name,item_price,product_id,item_stock;


}

public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
        final ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    final ViewHolder holder;
    LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();


    if (convertView == null) {

        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.submenutext, null);

        if(ITEM_AVALIABLE_QUANTITY.equalsIgnoreCase("0")){

            convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.heading);
        }
        /*else{
            convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sub_menu);
        }*/
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.product_id = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.hide_text);
        holder.item_name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
        holder.item_price = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.price);
        //holder.item_stock = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.stock);

        convertView.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    final HashMap<String, String> map = list.get(position);
    holder.product_id.setText(map.get(PRODUCT_ID));
    holder.item_name.setText(map.get(ITEM_NAME_COLUMN));
    holder.item_price.setText(map.get(ITEM_PRICE_COLUMN));
    holder.item_stock.setText(map.get(ITEM_AVALIABLE_QUANTITY));

    /*if(holder.item_stock.equals("0")){

        convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.heading);
    }*/

    return convertView;
}
```

}

Comment: Modify the view background based on `out-of-stock` data in your adapter.

Comment: you're gonna need to set a flag for the item(s) position in the `ListView`. then call your setBackground methods in the `getView` method of the listview's adapter.

Comment: yeah, use base adapter, and for every view you can set another color :) for example if you pass list with colors.. so for every view position you will get another color from that list

Comment: @Henry how to set,i have no idea to change the specific row background.

Comment: @Lumma not able to set it in simple adapter.

Comment: @Yugesh so try create class extending BaseAdapter, see here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html don't worry for code, you are focused on that class with base adapter. This code should be very easy to understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send data to your custom adapter which having it's own customize layout.

Main.java

```
  ListAdapter  adapter = new ListAdapter(this, arrayList);//ListAdapter is custom Adapter  
hotelList.setAdapter(adapter);  // hotellist is instance of ListView
```

Here is your custom Adapter .java file. this class have one separate view i.e. list_row.

```
public class LazyAdapterForReminder extends BaseAdapter {    
private Activity activity;   
private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;   

public LazyAdapterForReminder(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
    activity = a;
    data=d;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

}

public int getCount() {
    return data.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi=convertView;
    if(convertView==null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);
 TextView lv = (TextView)vi.findViewByID(R.id.blabla);    

   if(stock==o)
       lv.setBackgroundResource(R.color.red);
   else
       lv.setBackgroundResource(R.color.green);

    return vi;
}
```

}

Comment: see my code in above.it will display all details but not able to set background.

Comment: @Yugesh: where is your getView method? without getView method how can you play with your item of that view?

Comment: still your are not able to set color?

Comment: see my updated item. do you want to set background to your listview right? then take instance of listview and set background to it..

Comment: how to use list view inside the base adapter.

Comment: take listview in your main.xml class and in your listrow.xml you can use one textview or some thing else and asign background to that textview. see my updated answer..

Comment: Note that if you do lv.setBackgroundColor() instead of lv.setBackgroundResource() it will have unexpected consequences in changing the background color of other views.

Comment: @Amy It is just variable. you can check any condition instead of `stock==0` .It's just example. use your condition there.

Comment: I have checked position in if condition but that setting background color to multiple ListItems

Comment: @Amy used like this. if you want to set different background to 3rd item of listview then use `if(position==2) lv.setBackgroundResource(R.color.red);` in else use your default background.

Comment: Post your code in separate question and description and send link.. will take a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

I hope that you familiar with writing Custom Adapter to set on List View. You manage your List items with out of stock product state along with product name and date. On CustomAdapter getView method you can check state and set background of you list item color or else set correponding image drawable.
For Eg:

```
   @Override        
     public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) { 


                               if(stock==0){
                                        convertView.setBackgroundColor(R.color.grey);
                                 }else{
                                        convertView.setBackgroundColor(R.color.red);
                                   }

                          return convertView;
                    }
```

Comment: @Amy, stock is a value which controls the view background.It might be the value from your data model. If stock==0 set the appropriate color for your view else if stock!=0 set different color for that particular view.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the background in your Adapter getView.
The code would look like this:

```
        @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


        ViewHolder holder = null;

          if (convertView == null) {


            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)  getContext().getSystemService (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.listsearchitem, null);
            }

  //.................

            // then you could set the backgorun for the out of stock products
            convertView.setBackgroundResource(resid)

            //.................
      }
```